# Ubuntu 22.04 crashes when laptop is on battery power

Tags: freeze, battery, crash

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 alongside my original Windows 11 in my Dell laptop. Ubuntu runs fine when my laptop is plugged in, but it keeps on freezing when on battery power. This happens even though I have kept my laptop on "performance" mode (as opposed to "battery saver" or "balanced" throughout, even when it's on battery power.